# SwiftUI: Iterate over JSON Response

Tags: swiftui

I'm new to SwiftUI and I'm trying to understand how to iterate over an array of arrays from an API response.

I have decoded the response and the data looks good in `debugPrint(upcomingEvents)`

Tried unwrapping optional, and following a few guides with no luck yet.

Error in View:

```
Cannot convert value of type '[UpcomingEventData]' (aka 'Array<Array<UpcomingEventDatum>>') to expected argument type 'Binding<C>'
```

The error happens here in VStack on ForEach attempt:

```
  @State private var upcomingEvents: [UpcomingEventData]?
      ....
            VStack {
                if let events = upcomingEvents {
                     ForEach(events) { event in
                        Text(event)
                    }
                }
            }
            .task {
                do {
                    upcomingEvents = try await asyncUE.fetchWP()
       ...
```

upcomingEvents does have data and `debugPrint(type(of: upcomingEvents))`
`Swift.Optional<Swift.Array<Swift.Array<WW.UpcomingEventDatum>>>`

Model:

```
// MARK: - UpcomingEventDatum
struct UpcomingEventDatum: Codable, Identifiable {
    let name: String
    let id: Int
    let txt, closeDate, headliners: String
    let logo: String
    let athleteImgOne: String
    let athleteAltOne: String
    let athleteImgTwo: String
    let athleteAltTwo: String
    let products: [Product]
    let url: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name, id, txt
        case closeDate = "close_date"
        case headliners, logo
        case athleteImgOne = "athlete_img_one"
        case athleteAltOne = "athlete_alt_one"
        case athleteImgTwo = "athlete_img_two"
        case athleteAltTwo = "athlete_alt_two"
        case products, url
    }
}

// MARK: - Product
struct Product: Codable, Identifiable {
    let btnTxt, url, id: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case btnTxt = "btn_txt"
        case url, id
    }
}

typealias UpcomingEventData = [UpcomingEventDatum]
```

Comment: You have an array of arrays -- at the least, you won't be able to use `id: \.self` on that (which is generally a bad idea anyway). You should have `Identifiable` data. To debug further, it would help to have a [mre]

Comment: how did you define `upcomingEvents` and what is `UpcomingEventData`

Comment: It looks like you declared `upcomingEvents: [UpcomingEventData]` instead of `upcomingEvents: [UpcomingEventDatum]` 
or simply `upcomingEvents: UpcomingEventData`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your `upcomingEvents` is an array of array of `UpcomingEventDatum`.

To remove the error use:

```
  @State private var upcomingEvents: UpcomingEventData?
```

and

```
  Text(event.name)
```